# Can I use storage_path() when declare the PHP class constant?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to declare and initialize the path to `json` file in PHP class constant (outside the method). However, it looks like I can not call the `storage_path()` function outside the method.

```
class MainController extends Controller{

    const PATH_TO_JSON_DATA = storage_path().'data/data.json'; // invalid expression

    public function renderPage(){

        dd(storage_path().'data/data.json'); // valid expression

    }
}
```

Is it way to avoid to initialize the path inside the method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize the path to a private property in the constructor of your controller.

```
class MainController extends Controller
{

    private $jsonPath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jsonPath = storage_path().'data/data.json';
    }

}
```

According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) :

> Class constants must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a property, or a function call.